# ( Get-ChildItem c:\MyFolder | Measure-Object ).Count results in ObjectNotFound

Tags: powershell

The command

```
( Get-ChildItem c:\MyFolder | Measure-Object ).Count
```

sometimes gives the error

> - CategoryInfo          :ObjectNotFound: (:\MyFolder\myfile.xml:String) [Get-ChildItem], IOException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

It is correct that the object that cannot be found has been moved to the folder by another process but how to make not checking more than once?

To be clear, the problem is not the missing object but that the count files if the content change between Time1 and Time2 - and I dont get what Time2 is.

EDIT
I have simplified it and added some switches - partly at random

This exactly what I do

```
$i = 0
ForEach ($file in $files) { 
    
    ProcessOneFile ($file)
    start-sleep -Milliseconds 500
    $i++
    if ($i -eq 100) {
        write-host '100'
        while((Get-ChildItem -force -file -name $Myfolder'\*xml').Count -gt 200)
        {
             write-host 'too many, wait 30 sec'
             start-sleep -Milliseconds 30000
        }
        $i = 0
    }
  
}
```

Comment: Can you rephrase what you're asking for? Not quite sure I understand.

Comment: I have tried - the problem is simply that count does not work for me and my assumption is that the cause is that one of the missing files are removed before the counting is completed.

But it seems unlikely so perhaps I miss something else....

Comment: By the way, you don't need Measure-Object at all there ... `( Get-ChildItem c:\MyFolder).Count` is enough.

Comment: Yes, I have now changed to Get-ChildItem -force -name -file c:\MyFolder).Count  and is running a new test. It does not fail every time so we will see.

The only other thing is that I do it in a while condition - if it fail again I will store the count in a variable instead before use

Comment: added -force -file & -name a bit on random. Testing ok so far but it never failed everytime.

Comment: @SagePourpre I do sleep in every iteration and only check number of files each 100 iteration  and if gt 200  I sleep 30s until next check.

EDIT But for testing purpose the sleep is lower than normal now - if / when it fails I will put back the normal 500ms x 100 intervall

Comment: Added the loops in the sample above.

Still running...maybe it is ok now but unclear why

Comment: @SagePourpre That is a typo. It does not fail every time so shouldn't be anything like that. I miss something obvious in my loops or there are a timing issue in the command.

The code  I just added in the question should be correct - and like I said, the code does what it should with the correct paths - it is just the count failing sometimes.

The files in the destination folders will be consumed by another processes so a moving content is to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it works if -name is used. I suppose it disconnects the collection from the actual file system. Surprising to me but I lack the indepth knowledge (clearly)

So for count only
`(Get-ChildItem -name -force -file  $MyDir'\*xml').Count`

Is the safer bet